# log4j2 status messages with composite configurations

Tags: java, log4j2

I have multiple log4j2 configurations which are merging in my application into a [composite configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#CompositeConfiguration). I'm interested in status property of each configuration. How will log4j2 configure [status logging](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#StatusMessages) if each part of composite configuration has it's own status level?